# check if value is numeric do something

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to check if a value passed is either a string or a number with the below script

```
$scope.checkval=function(res){
    console.log(res.profile_id)
    if(angular.isNumber(res.profile_id)){
        console.log('Number');
     }else {
        console.log('Center Code is not a number');
     }
}
```

from the above code i'm always getting `Center code is not a number`, though the value passed is numeric

Comment: Unless there is a bug in `angular.isNumber()`, then the value is **not** a `Number` after all

Comment: Can you show us the value of `res.profile_id`

Comment: `isNumber` is pretty much equivalent to using `typeof value === 'number'`, and any string would fail that.

Answer (score 1):

That API is not for checking to see if a *string* is a number; it's checking to see whether the value already is a number.

The simplest thing to do is use the `+` unary operator to coerce the value to be a number, and then use `!isNaN()` to verify that it was in fact a parseable numeric string.

```
$scope.checkval = function(n) {
  return !isNaN(+n);
};
```

That'll return `true` when the value can be converted to an actual number. Note that the constant `NaN` is also a number, but you probably don't want to include `NaN` in your definition of "numeric".

Comment: can you put it in my script

Answer (score 0):

`isNumber` is a pretty accurate function so I personally would believe that the value you are passing is probably a string.  But in order to avoid that potential issue you can do this, it will eliminate the potential for a string thats a number, but not correct a string that is not.

```
$scope.checkval = function(res){
    //unary operator will convert the string into a number if appropriate
    var numberToCheck = +res;
    if (angular.isNumber(numberToCheck)) {
        console.log('Number');
     } else {
        console.log('Center Code is not a number');
     }
}
```

Pointy's solution is a much better way to go about it if you don't want to/can't use the angular built in functions

Answer (score 0):

Is the variable being passed like this '5' or this 5.

`res.profile_id = 5; //would come out as true`

```
res.profile_id = '5'; //would come out as false
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that res.profile_id is actually a string.

if you are expecting it to be an integer (like if it is a primary key coming back from the DB), you can caste it explicitly to an int by using:

```
res.profile_id = parseInt(res.profile_id, 10);
```

If this is a user input field or it is likely that there would be text in the response, you can test for it like so:

```
if (!isNaN(res.profile_id){
    ...
}
```